# Uploading preprints of old Elsevier papers to arXiv, and updating arXiv preprints by newer versions

Tags: publications, arxiv, preprint, license, elsevier

Let's say that my first scientific paper was published in 2010 in one of the Elsevier mathematical journals. At that time I didn't care about uploading a preprint of the paper to arXiv which I now regret. Is it ok to upload the paper to arXiv today? Do I break my license agreement with Elsevier by doing this? Is it appropriate?

Also, let's say that I uploaded a preprint of another paper to arXiv 6 months ago and at the same time I submitted the paper to one of the Elsevier journals. I was asked by the Elsevier reviewer to make a revision of the paper. I made the revision and the paper was accepted for a publication. Is it ok to replace the original preprint on arXiv by the latest version of the paper which will be published by the Elsevier journal?

Finally, assuming that the answer to the previous question is affirmative. Is it ok to replace an original preprint of yet another paper by its latest version even if the paper was published three years ago (but I never replaced the original preprint by any newer version)?

Comment: Hi, I added 'Elsevier' to your title since the question mainly seems to be about their preprint policy. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: Yes, it should be okay -- see the 2013 version of their license policy at https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20131022235944/http://www.elsevier.com/about/open-access/oa-and-elsevier/oa-license-policy . It lets you do the same even for other people's papers (cf. http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/dkr1978.pdf ).

Answer (score 4):

This is covered on the [Elsevier website](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing). Some key points:

> An accepted manuscript is the manuscript of an article that has been accepted for publication and which typically includes author-incorporated changes suggested during submission, peer review, and editor-author communications. They do not include other publisher value-added contributions such as copy-editing, formatting, technical enhancements and (if relevant) pagination.

and

> Authors can update their preprints on arXiv or RePEc with their accepted manuscript.

and

> Preprints should not be added to or enhanced in any way in order to appear more like, or to substitute for, the final versions of articles.